# How to add an attribute to specific elements in an XML document?

Tags: xml

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="xxx" creationtoolversion="1.0" o-tmf="Format" datatype="xml" segtype="sentence" adminlang="en-US" srclang="en-US" creationdate="20160224T124311Z" creationid="xxx">
    <prop type="x-Quality:Integer"></prop>
    <prop type="x-Comment:SingleString"></prop>
    <prop type="x-Recognizers">RecognizeAll</prop>
    <prop type="x-TMName">templates</prop>
    <prop type="x-TokenizerFlags">DefaultFlags</prop>
    <prop type="x-WordCountFlags">BreakOnTag</prop>
  </header>
  <body>
    <tu creationdate="20160224T130930Z" creationid="alignment" changedate="20160224T131623Z" changeid="alignment" lastusagedate="20160224T130930Z">
      <prop type="x-Origin">Alignment</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Draft</prop>
      <prop type="x-Comment:SingleString">Testing</prop>
      <prop type="x-Quality:Integer">50</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>Version 10, 02/2016</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg>10 versija, 2016/02</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu creationdate="20160224T130930Z" creationid="alignment" changedate="20160224T130930Z" changeid="alignment" lastusagedate="20160224T130930Z">
      <prop type="x-Origin">Alignment</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Draft</prop>
      <prop type="x-Quality:Integer">88</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>ANNEX I</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg>I PRIEDAS</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu creationdate="20160224T130930Z" creationid="alignment" changedate="20160224T130930Z" changeid="alignment" lastusagedate="20160224T130930Z">
      <prop type="x-Origin">Alignment</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Draft</prop>
      <prop type="x-Quality:Integer">93</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>SUMMARY OF PRODUCT CHARACTERISTICS</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg>PREPARATO CHARAKTERISTIKŲ SANTRAUKA</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu creationdate="20160224T130930Z" creationid="alignment" changedate="20160224T130930Z" changeid="alignment" lastusagedate="20160224T130930Z">
      <prop type="x-Origin">Alignment</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Draft</prop>
      <prop type="x-Quality:Integer">91</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg><bpt i="1" type="pt40" x="1" />&lt;<ept i="1" /><ph x="2" type="ph41" /><bpt i="3" type="pt42" x="3" />This medicinal product is subject to additional monitoring.<ept i="3" /></seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg><bpt i="1" type="pt40" x="1" />&lt;<ept i="1" /><ph x="2" type="ph41" /><bpt i="3" type="pt42" x="3" />Vykdoma papildoma šio vaistinio preparato stebėsena.<ept i="3" /></seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu creationdate="20160224T130930Z" creationid="alignment" changedate="20160224T130930Z" changeid="alignment" lastusagedate="20160224T130930Z">
      <prop type="x-Origin">Alignment</prop>
      <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Draft</prop>
      <prop type="x-Quality:Integer">90</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="en-US">
        <seg>This will allow quick identification of new safety information.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="lt-LT">
        <seg>Tai padės greitai nustatyti naują saugumo informaciją.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

I want to add this attribute written below to all "body" elements "tu":

```
<prop type="x-Comment:SingleString">Testing</prop>
```

(I've already added it to the first element as an example.) What tool can I use and how to add or copy this attribute to all `<tu>` elements (there are hundreds of them)?

Comment: As it stands, this looks offtopic, because it's product recommendation, not a coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "attribute" is indeed another element containing an attribute

```
<prop type="x-Comment:SingleString">Testing</prop>
```

Tools you could use are XSLT-processors. They will transform an input XML to an output XML.

Using a XSLT-processor with this XSLT gives the desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" priority="-1"> <!-- copy everything unless another template with higher priority says otherwise -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tu">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />          <!-- copies all attributes of 'tu' -->
      <prop type="x-Comment:SingleString">Testing</prop>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />      <!-- copies all sub-nodes of 'tu' -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```